# Spock - stubbing the JSON response

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I use Grails 3.1.7 with inbuilt spock. It looks like I'm having troubles with stubbing a return value of service that is rendered by controller during the unit-tests execution. Service method returns null and then controller throws a GroovyRuntimeException complaining that "Cannot resolve which method to invoke" because of the "null" returned.

A sample of the controller's action code:

```
def register(RequestRegistrationCommand rrc) {
    //some logic
    render ajaxResponseService.composeJsonResponse(rrc)
}
```

A sample of service's method code:

```
JSON composeJsonResponse(instance, String successMessage = null) {
    //some logic
    [success: success, messages: messages] as JSON
}
```

Parts of the test suite code:

```
//field definitions
def requestRegistrationCommand = Mock(RequestRegistrationCommand)
def ajaxResponseService = Mock(AjaxResponseService)

def setup() {
    controller.ajaxResponseService = ajaxResponseService
    .....
}

void "Testing register() action"() {
    when: 'Passing invalid register params'
    ...
    params.email = INVALID_EMAIL
    controller.register(requestRegistrationCommand)

    then: 'JSON response returned'
    ...
    1 * ajaxResponseService.composeJsonResponse(requestRegistrationCommand) >> [asd:123] as JSON //tried plenty of things here
}
```

The funny thing is that the interaction itself is triggered (checked by replacing it with "0 * _", and also put " 1 * ajaxR... >> 'asd'" with getting an error that string could not be cast into JSON). So the interaction might have return some stubbed value but anyway in most cases that I tried the controller behaves as if it tries to render null:

> groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for
>   method
>   grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer$Trait$Helper#render.
>   Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class
>   com.tempvs.controllers.AuthController, null] due to overlapping
>   prototypes between:   [interface
>   grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer, interface
>   java.lang.CharSequence]   [interface
>   grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer, interface
>   java.util.Map]    [interface
>   grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer, interface
>   org.grails.web.converters.Converter]  at
>   com.tempvs.controllers.AuthController.register(AuthController.groovy:45)
>     at com.tempvs.controllers.AuthControllerSpec.Testing register()
>   action(AuthControllerSpec.groovy:97)

What am I doing wrong and how should I force the mocked service object return non-null value to avoid controllers render failing?

Please notify me if more info is needed, I tried to be as brief as I can. Thanks in advance!

**UPD**
The test passed for interaction:

```
1 * ajaxResponseService.composeJsonResponse(requestRegistrationCommand) >> Mock(JSON)
```

when I changed AjaxResponseService#composeJsonResponse() return type from *JSON* to *def*. But come on, I use just a mocked collaborator for testing and how can I force it to support the explicit type?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved it by mocking the return value:

```
def json = Mock(JSON)
....
1 * ajaxResponseService.composeJsonResponse(requestRegistrationCommand) >> json
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a closure for your return value:

```
1 * ajaxResponseService.composeJsonResponse(requestRegistrationCommand) >> { [asd:123] as JSON }
```

See (refer to the section on return values):

http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1-rc-3/interaction_based_testing.html

You may be able to just wrap the return with parentheses:

```
1 * ajaxResponseService.composeJsonResponse(requestRegistrationCommand) >> ( [asd:123] as JSON )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems that the mocking of JSON object was fairly enough to make it work :)